# Can we config edit rectangle in UIImagePickerController

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

I use UIImagePickerController and set allowsEditing YES. My question is how to change the edit rectangle? or it is fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try a lot and find out that, it is fixed.
Once we want to do this effect, maybe we have to build a image picker one by our own instead of using the `UIImagePickerController`.